Nullable diagnostic CS8621 raised without reason
I have a razor component in a separate project that defines a search parameter like this:
[Parameter, EditorRequired]
public Func<string, Task<IEnumerable<T>>> Search { get; set; } = default!;

The consumer component (contained in a separate, consuming project) defines a Search function like this:
async Task<IEnumerable<Combination>> Search(string term)
{
...
}

And the kind nullability analyzers shout:

Nullability of reference types in return type of 'Task<IEnumerable> HandoutForm.Search(string term)' doesn't match the target delegate 'Func<string, Task<IEnumerable<Combination?>>>' (possibly because of nullability attributes).CS8621

I've tried to reproduce this issue with a simple class using all possible combinations of IEnumerable, Task and compile-time known argument vs generic and does not reproduce:
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<InnerTest> InnerTests { get; } = [];
    public Task<IEnumerable<InnerTest>> InnerTestsAsync { get; } = Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<InnerTest>>([]);
}

public class GenericTest<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; } = [];
    public Task<IEnumerable<T>> ItemsAsync { get; } = Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<T>>([]);
    public Func<string, Task<IEnumerable<T>>> Search { get; set; } = default!;
}


public class InnerTest
{
}

var test = new Test();
var innerTests = test.InnerTests;

if (innerTests.Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine("test");
}

var genericTest = new GenericTest<Test>();
var innerGenericTests = genericTest.Items;

if (innerGenericTests.Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine("generic test");
}
var innerGenericTaskTests = await genericTest.ItemsAsync;
if (innerGenericTaskTests.Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine("generic test");
}
genericTest.Search = testSearch; // should be identical as far as nullable goes.

static Task<IEnumerable<Test>> testSearch(string term) => Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Test>>([]);

While being structurally identical as far as I can tell, no errors are raised. The only culprit I can think of is the razor precompiler, maybe?
Anyone has any ideas how can I tell the analyzer not to derp on me?  I don't see how I can decorate the Func definition with NotNull and I'm out of ideas. Do I just have to pragma supress?

Please don't use = null! or = default! to initialize a reference-type property.

Why not? This is the official MS approach when necessary - for example when injecting dependencies in razor components.

Ok, as usual writing out the problem helped out with the solution, the issue was indeed related to how the razor component's generic parameter is auto-inferred:
<MyComponent @bind-Value=_value" ... />

@code { 
    MyType? _value;
}

This essentially makes the T itself a MyType?, obvious in retrospect, which is why the return type of the search funtion missmatches and shouts.
The solutions are two, depending on the situation:

Change _value to non-nullable
Change the Search function implementation to return nullable.

In my case I chose option 2, because I don't have default value.
